# Spark SQL - registered temporary table not found

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, spark-cassandra-connector

I run the following command:

```
spark-shell --packages datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:1.6.0-s_2.10
```

Then I stop the context with:

```
sc.stop
```

Then I run this code in the REPL:

```
val conf = new org.apache.spark.SparkConf(true).set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")
val sc = new org.apache.spark.SparkContext(conf)
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
val cc = new org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSQLContext(sc)

cc.setKeyspace("ksp")

cc.sql("SELECT * FROM continents").registerTempTable("conts")

val allContinents = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM conts").collect
```

And I get:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table not found: conts;
```

The keyspace `ksp` and table `continents` are defined in Cassandra, so I suspect the error isn't from that side.

(Spark 1.6.0,1.6.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use different context for creating dataframe and execute SQL.

```
val conf = new 
org.apache.spark.SparkConf(true).set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")
val sc = new org.apache.spark.SparkContext(conf)
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
val cc = new org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSQLContext(sc)

cc.setKeyspace("ksp")

cc.sql("SELECT * FROM continents").registerTempTable("conts")

// use cc instead of sqlContext
val allContinents = cc.sql("SELECT * FROM conts").collect
```